# Swift autolayout, setting constraints for a container view

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am creating a simple app for storing some permanent values and am stuck trying to get the layout how I want. I have done some basic autolayout tutorials, but I can't seem to condense this question into Google searchable format.

I am trying to set constraints for a Container View, which I want to be

1. centered horizontally, and
2. a set number of pixels from the item above it (actually, I'd love it to be a % of the screen down from the next element up, but I'm new to layouts).

For the other items in the View, I am able to set just these 2 constraints, and everything is blue.

[Layout of Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeB4I.png)

When I apply the same constraints to this Container View, the constraints are Red, and the Container View does not appear correctly when I run the app.

[Layout of Container View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdb5Z.png)

Is it the case that I need to learn a lot more about Container Views or Autolayout, or is it something simple and different about this particular view/element?

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel`s' intristic size vary from the length of the text they contain.

Since a container view does not have such a thing, you should set up **leading/trailing constraints** or a **width** and a **center constraint** for it.

[image: constraints without error]

I would recommend to also do this for the labels, since they can easily be too long and be partially hidden this way.